# Angular2 child routes

Tags: angular, angular-route-segment

I have root module and a child module in angular2, both has its own routes defined.
  In child module am configuring RouterModule as

```
RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
```

In root module(parent) , am configuring RouterModule as

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
```

I am using same **routes names** in both child and root

In child

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent }, //outputs I am child
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent }
];
```

In root (parent)

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent }, //outputs I am parent
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent }
];
```

I am importing child module in root module

```
import .....
import {AppModule as ChildModule} from 'child-module/src/app/app.module';


@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ChildModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })

  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

When I load my component (I mean root module), default route is always going to child module instead of rootmodule ie its printing "I am child" ,where as I expect "i am parent", child route should be loaded only when I load it, how can I route it to default route of root (parent) module instead of child module?

Comment: have you considered adding child path which will be loaded lazily in the parent route, something like `{ path: child, loadChildren:'path to child module'}`? You may read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: @Madhu Ranjan, issue is child (default)routes is getting loaded by default even without configuring which I want to avoid

Comment: Have you configured child route in child module? If yes then when you import child module in app module child routes will be added..

Comment: Got it now, I think I cannot have default routes in parent as well as child,able to solve it by re factoring the code, thank you very much

Comment: @sudharsantk Can you provide your solution? im encountering the exact same situation

Comment: @KesemDavid  , there are two ways you can solve, if you are lazy loading , you can directly name the route like you want   2) or else at child module level introduce top level route name for eg                  export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '/child1',      children:[ <your child routes goes here]}
];

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your question:

Angular's router matches routes from the top down. The first route which matches is the one the router navigates to. You load the `ChildModule`'s routes before the `RootModule`'s routes, and that means those routes all have priority over the `RootModule`'s routes. When navigating to `''`, the router will first check the `ChildModule`'s routes, find a match and take you there. If you swap the places of `ChildModule` and `RootModule` in the `imports` statement, then `RootModule`'s routes would always be navigated to.

You can learn more at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html.

Comment: Unforutnately, it did not work for me, tried both `Child before Router` and `Router before Child`, did not work..